# Split column values based on flag in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have a table as below:

```
Sex weight hight
M    34      5'6"
F    29      5'1"
M    29      4'5"
F    26      5'2"
```

And i want to display table as below through python pandas

```
M                 F
Height Weight    Height Weight
5'6"   34        5'1"     29
4'5"   29        5'2"     26
```

to parallel compare Male and female Ht and wt data.

Comment: Are you already familiar with the `groupby` function? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: What if the numbers of rows in ``M`` and ``F`` are different?

Comment: Have you simply tried something like this `df.set_index(['Sex', 'Height', 'Weight']).sort_index()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly but it works. The idea is to split the original `DataFrame` in two by sex and to recombine them with a hierarchical column index.

```
# Test data
df =pd.DataFrame({'Sex': ['M','F','M','F'], 'Weight': [34,29,29,26], 'Height': [5.6,5.1,4.5,5.2]})

def reshape(grouped, group):
    df = grouped.get_group(group).loc[:,['Height','Weight']]
    df.columns = [[group, group],df.columns]
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)

grouped = df.groupby('Sex')
pd.concat([reshape(grouped,'M'), reshape(grouped,'F')], axis=1)

       M             F       
  Height Weight Height Weight
0    5.6     34    5.1     29
1    4.5     29    5.2     26
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid defining a function with this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex': ['M','F','M','F'], 'Weight': [34,29,29,26], 'Height': [5.6,5.1,4.5,5.2]})
gr = df.groupby('Sex')
grs = [grs for name, grs in gr]
for each in grs:
    del each['Sex']
    each.index = range(len(each.index))

mI = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([gr.groups.keys(), grs[0].columns])
results = pd.concat(grs, axis=1)
results.columns = mI
print results
```

Which prints:

```
       M             F
  Height Weight Height Weight
0    5.1     29    5.6     34
1    5.2     26    4.5     29
```

Comment: This solution worked if i apply group by column only on Sex field. Howver another  requirement says the below format:                                 Date  Sex weight hight    Salary
Feb 2014  M    34      5'6"    20,000
Feb 2015  F    29      5'1"    20,000
Feb 2014  M    29      4'5"    10,000
Feb 2015  F    26      5'2"    40,000
    Desired format:                                                                                                                                          M             F
 Date    Salary Salary
Feb 2014  30,000 60,000

Comment: @Rocky, I'm afraid I don't exactly understand what you're asking for. You could look into the groupby documentation here to try and work it out: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
You'll probably also want to look at these more practical examples: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html